# Swift compiler cannot distinguish two initializers

Tags: swift

Basically, I have a class called UserData and multiple initializers for it. In particular, I have a copy initializer which looks like:

```
init (_ origin: UserData){
    // copy over everything
}
```

And another initializer which is used when I need to read the data from a file:

```
convenience init (Read _: Bool) {
    // read stuff and call another initializer
}
```

Then I always got a compiler error saying cannot convert Bool to UserData whenever I tried to do `var something = UserData(true)`.
I tried adding label, but compiler said extroneous label since there is only one parameter. I could make a workaround by adding another random parameter to the second initializer. But why is the compiler always trying to interpret the call to something does not match the type while there is another that matches the type?

Comment: Do you mean `convenience init(_ read: Bool) {`? The underscore has to come first (and parameters should be camel case).

Comment: Also, there's nothing special about having 1 parameter. You're telling the compiler there's no label by adding the `_`. If you say `convenience init(read: Bool) {` then you would call it with `UserData(read: true)`.

Comment: You have declared your convenience initializer wrong.  It should have been `init(_ read: Bool)`.  Or, otherwise, you should invoke it like this: `var something = UserData(Read: true)`.

Answer (score 1):

Swift has no problem distinguishing two initializers with one parameter. The error is because of how the second one is defined. It should be:

```
convenience init (_ read: Bool) {
    // read stuff and call another initializer
}
```